# Finding a $C^1$ function that satisfies several conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Suppose $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0 \leq r_1 < r_2$. Show that there is a $C^1$ function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$\begin{cases} f(\mathbf{x})=0 & \rVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\rVert \geq r_2 \\ 0<f(\mathbf{x})<1 & r_1 < \   \rVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\rVert < r_2 \\ f(\mathbf{x})=1 & \rVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0 \rVert \leq r_1 \end{cases}$$

I tried to define $f$ as a composition. First we define $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, h(\mathbf{x})=\rVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0 \rVert^2$. Then we look for $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is a cubic polynomial with $g(r_1^2)=1, g(r_2^2)=g'(r_2^2)=g'(r_1^2)=0$.

In other words, if $g(x)=\beta(x-r_2^2)^2(x-\alpha)$, then we're looking for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\beta(r_1^2-r_2^2)^2(r_1^2-\alpha) = 1 \\ \frac{d}{dx}\big[\beta(x-r_2^2)^2(x-\alpha)\big]\bigg|_{x=r_1^2}=0$$

Let's assume $\alpha,\beta$ exist (how do I prove this?). Then we define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$ f(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases} 0 && \rVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\rVert \geq r_2 \\ (g \circ h)(\mathbf{x}) && r_1 < \   \rVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\rVert < r_2 \\ 1 && \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\rVert \leq r_1  \end{cases}$$

Since $C^1$ functions are closed under composition, $f$ is $C^1$.

**Did I mess this up?**

Answer (score 0):

Although I am inclined to use bump functions and do this all $C^\infty$, your approach seems OK to me. It's easier (for me, anyhow) to shift this over and look for a polynomial $P$ with $P(0)=1$ and $P'(0)=P(A)=P'(A)=0$. Then I know that $P(x)=(x-A)^2(ax+b)$, where I now must choose $a$ and $b$ so that $P(0)=1$ and $P'(0)=0$. This means that I need $b=1/A^2$ and $a=2/A^3$, I do believe. Now you're going to want $f(\mathbf x) = P(\|\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0\|^2-r_1^2)$ with $A=r_2^2-r_1^2$.